# How to connect to Oracle db from SSIS/SQL Server Data Tools?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, odbc, oracleclient

I have Oracle 11g r2 client installed on my 64 bit machine running Windows Server 2008 r2. Have the following installed:
SQL Server 64 bit
MS Office 64 bit

I tried connecting from excel/powerpivot to the oracle db, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to connect from SSIS to the Oracle db, I get a mismatch between the driver and application.

> ### (TITLE: Connection Manager
>
> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
>   contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application )

How do I overcome this issue? 
Thanks!

Comment: One thing to look at would be if you have 64-bit Office installed, you probably have 64-bit Oracle drivers installed. SQL Management studio and other SQL Server tools are afaik always 32-bit and would require 32-bit Oracle drivers.

Comment: SSMS is 64 bit, checked that. So I'm guessing SSIS is also 64 bit. In this case, how do I get it to work? Should I install a 32bit oracle driver as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need configure Oracle ODBC Driver 32 bit on:

> c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

SSIS of server 2008 r2 is always running on 32 bit no matter what SSIS say:)

1. You need to edit runtime of SSIS package and set it to false to find 32 bit ODBC driver (first window)
   http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx
2. In "Agent" Job Step properties "Execution options" tab you need check "Use 32bit runtime" option.